# CryptographicException: Access denied OpenFlags.ReadWrite

Tags: .net, windows, file-permissions, x509certificate2

Getting Access denied when trying to open local certificate store with OpenFlags.ReadWrite. It works fine when i use OpenFlags.MaxAllowed. I tried granting Read/Write permissions to folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys but still no luck. Any ideas what folder permissions I need Read/Write access to?

Here is my code

```
private void Run()
{
    //grab the certs that are on the local machine
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

   
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

                    
    store.Close();
}
```

Comment: The C:\ProgramData folder [requires elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/17034) when writing is intended.

Answer (score 1):

The application must be executed under local administrators account in order to open local machine store in write mode.